# Pytesseract OCR not returning proper result on captcha image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

i am using tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1

I have the following image

[ocr image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1MTF.png)

i have converted this image using opencv

[converted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wqYP.png)

```
img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=5, fy=5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 9)
_, img = cv2.threshold(img, 185, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

my tesseract commend

```
tesseract image.png stdout -l eng-best --oem 1 --psm 7
```

getting result: **NVRG nk**

but result should be : **nvRGnk**

Answer (score 2):

Starting from your converted image, just need a little more filtering
[image]

> nvRGnk

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('2.png',0)
image = 255 - image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
dilate_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2,2))
dilate = cv2.dilate(close, dilate_kernel, iterations=1)
result = 255 - dilate 

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang='eng',config='--psm 13')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```